# How to regularly update symbolic link (ln -sf) via crontab

Tags: cron, symlink, ln

#### Background

The PNG image files I want to use is stored in directories according to date, for example:
    `/NAS-mein/data/201812/`
PNG stored within it like `/NAS-mein/data/201812/foo/bar/20181231_1500.png`

So I created a symbolic link `PNG_path` in my home directory
`ln -s /NAS-mein/data/201812/  PNG_path`

and I'm able to update it manually through:
`ln -sf /NAS-mein/data/201812/  PNG_path`
which works fine and returns `` `PNG_path' -> `/NAS-mein/data/201812' ``

I'm in a CentOS 6.7 environment and I don't have superuser privilege.
The destination directory is created by the others but granted 777 permission, i.e.:
`drwxrwxrwx /NAS-mein/`
`drwxrwxrwx /NAS-mein/data/`
`drwxrwxrwx /NAS-mein/data/201812/`

#### With Crontab

Then I tried to automatically update this symbolic link on the first day of month, so it will always redirect me to the directory of current date.
I tried start a job in crontab like:
`0 0 1 * *  ln -sf /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+%Y%m")  /home/me/PNG_path >>/home/me/.pngln.log  2>>&1`
but this does not work, even without giving any information to the log.
So I tried:
`0 0 1 * *  cd /home/me/  &&  ln -sf /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+%Y%m")  PNG_path >>.pngln.log  2>>&1`
and wrap it into a Bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash  
/bin/unlink  "/home/me/PNG_path"  
/bin/ln -sf /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+%Y%m")  PNG_path >>/home/me/.pngln.log  2>>&1
```

but all of above seem not working as the symbolic link does not change, 
and no any information was logged (i.e. `.pngln.log` is not created anyway.)

I'm not sure where I did it wrong, or using `ln` in `crontab` is just not a legit use?

Edit: I notice that I didn't write the most suspicious part: using date function in `ln` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign is special in crontab and needs to be escaped if you put your `date` command there (see `man 5 crontab`).

Your symbolic link points to a directory.  When you run `ln` again, it will put the link inside that directory.

Example:

```
$ mkdir real
$ ln -sf real link
$ tree
.
|-- link -> real
`-- real

1 directory, 1 file
```

```
$ ln -sf real link
$ tree
.
|-- link -> real
`-- real
    `-- real -> real

1 directory, 2 files
```

The solution is to use `ln` with `-n` (or `--no-dereference`) on Linux or on any system with GNU coreutils' `ln`, and with `-h` on BSD.  This would cause `ln` to not descend into the directory that the link points to before creating the new link.

A portable solution would be to first explicitly remove the link using `rm`:

```
ln -s some_directory link
```

Later:

```
rm link && ln -s some_directory link
```

Comment: I did some test following your explanation and it worked the way you described, including the problem that I add extra tailing `/`. But in real case it seem not the same, as no additional symlink was created inside destination directory. I will add some more description about the directory privilege in the question for additional clarity.

Comment: @ceoper Did you see what I added about `%` in crontab at the top of the answer?

Comment: Oh god, I mis-read it and thought it was the `$` symbol , and was trying around it. I will try to escape `%` symbol later.

Comment: Ok. I tested it on another CentOS 6.8 environment and it worked. I will later try to find out what is preventing me from doing this on that specific machine.

Comment: It turns out that in the early trials, the problem was the `%` in crontab as mentioned by @Kusalananda. And in later trials I wrote 2>>&1 (which I didn't update in my question description...) in my cron and caused the failure and no error message cannot be logged. Now I got things work out and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I want to sum up the mistakes that cause of the failure of my `crontab` `ln` schedule in this answer.
This is much thanks to Kusalananda's answer, I just organize them for record.

First, as mentioned by Kusalananda, if one is trying to update the symlink of a directory, the symlink will be created inside the directory, so one will need to set `-n` flag for `ln`, so the algorithm will not follow into the reference.

Good:

```
ln -nsf  /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+%Y%m")  PNG_path
```

Not working:

```
ln -nsf  /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+%Y%m")  PNG_path
```

Second, as mentioned by Kusalananda, the `%` has special meaning in cron, so it needs to be escaped.

Good:

```
0 0 1 * *  /bin/ln -nsf  /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+\%Y\%m")  PNG_path
```

Not working:

```
0 0 1 * *  /bin/ln -nsf  /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+%Y%m")  PNG_path
```

Third and the last, though this is actually not really related to `cron` or `ln`, that for `stderr` to append to the same destination of `stdout`, it cannot be written as `2>>&1`. Instead,  `2>&1` is correct. (Actually without `-v` flag for `ln`, it will output nothing, but one will at least see an empty log is created.)

Good:

```
0 0 1 * *  /bin/ln -nsf  /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+\%Y\%m")  PNG_path  >>.log  2>&1
```

Not working:

```
0 0 1 * *  /bin/ln -nsf  /NAS-mein/data/$(date "+\%Y\%m")  PNG_path  >>.log  2>>&1
```